# What's the best way to use Rxjava to get Dialog's input values?

Tags: android, mvvm, dialog, rx-java, viewmodel

I have a button inside the Activity. When I press this button, I want to execute some function with the input value after receiving input value from another Dialog.

I implemented this request in the following configuration.

ViewModel

```
package k.test.mvvmmock

import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable
import io.reactivex.Single

class MainViewModel(val contract: Contract) : BaseObservable() {

interface Contract {
    fun showDialog(): Single<String>
}


fun clickButton(){
    contract.showDialog()
        .subscribe({
            //Something Action
            println("Input : $it")
        },{

        })
}
}
```

Activity

```
package k.test.mvvmmock

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import io.reactivex.Single
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import io.reactivex.subjects.SingleSubject
import k.test.mvvmmock.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import java.lang.Exception


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainViewModel.Contract {
val viewModel = MainViewModel(this)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        .vm = viewModel
}

override fun showDialog(): Single<String> {
    val txt = EditText(this)
    val subject = SingleSubject.create<String>()
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Input")
        .setView(txt)
        .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
            subject.onSuccess(txt.text.toString())
        }
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
            subject.onError(Exception("Canceled!"))
        }
        .create()

    return subject.doOnSubscribe {
        dialog.show()
    }
        .doFinally {
            if(dialog.isShowing)
                dialog.dismiss()
        }
}
}
```

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<data>
    <variable name="vm" type="k.test.mvvmmock.MainViewModel"/>
</data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:onClick="@{(v)->vm.clickButton()}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Generally posted code uses the way that an Activity subscribes to a ViewModel using a Subject, etc., when it needs to pop up a dialog in the ViewModel, but the flow of receiving any value from the Dialog back to the ViewModel is inconsistent.

The above code also needs to pass the interface that receives the input value from the Activity to the ViewModel one by one.

I would like to improve this code, but I do not really have a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If an app passes a `View` reference to the ViewModel, the app is not following MVVM pattern. If an app follows MVVM, its ViewModel layer shouldn't need to know anything about its View layer.

The problem with the current `MainViewModel` is that it "tells" view to show the dialog, and "gets" the dialog data back to itself. The flow should be the other way around. `MainActivity` should be the one that "observes" the event and "give" data to `MainViewModel`.

Example:

**MainViewModel**

```
class MainViewModel : BaseObservable() { // No Contract!

    val showDialogEvent = PublishSubject.create<Any>();

    fun clickButton() {
        showDialogEvent.onNext(Any())
    }

    fun doThingsWith(dialogInput: String) {
        // do something here
        println("Input : $it")
    }

    fun handleError(e: Throwable) {
        // do something here
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ...

        val disposable = viewModel.showDialogEvent
            .subscribe {
                val txt = EditText(this)
                val subject = SingleSubject.create<String>()
                val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Input")
                    .setView(txt)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                        viewModel.doThingsWith(txt.text.toString())
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
                        viewModel.handleError(Exception("Canceled!"))
                    }
                    .create()

                dialog.show()
            }
    }
```

Additionally, if `ViewModel` doesn't need to know about the click you can further simplify the flow by setting click listener for the button directly from the `MainActivity`.